# Kotlin: Condition that double-value is a "normal" number

Tags: kotlin, double, nan, infinity, defensive-programming

How can I test if a value of type *Double* in Kotlin is not
`Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, Double.NaN` or some other special value?

I'd like to have something like `require(Double.isNormal(x))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/is-finite.html

`require(x.isFinite())` is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've answered your own question.... write a function that checks the 3 cases, and takes a lambda to run if the precondition is met:

```
fun ifNormal(double: Double, toDo: () -> Unit) {
    if (double != Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY 
        && double != Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY 
        && double != Double.NaN) {
        toDo()
    }
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
ifNormal(1.0) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: I think I'm gonna go with the solution of @al3c, but seeing how you could use functional arguments is nice too see too. Wouldn't have thought of that.

Comment: No worries, their answer addresses your question more directly to be fair.

Comment: I think `double != Double.NaN` will always return true, as NaN should compare not equal to any Double, NaN included.

Comment: Fair enough, I was just answering OP question, didn't do the graft to check all 3 conditions actually made sense

Comment: Although, according to: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/is-finite.html, it would appear that a double could be NaN?

Comment: Yup, you're wrong mate, from Primitives.kt, you can see: `public val NaN: Double`

Comment: This compiles fine; ` val d: Double = Double.NaN`

Comment: The problem is that then `d == Double.NaN` is false (and `!=` is true). This is how `NaN` works in basically every language. That's why there is a separate `d.isNaN()`.

Comment: Alexey Romanov - is that true? val d = Double.NaN; d == Double.NaN == false?